# Filtering based on another filter/condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to filter on a,b, and c (but c only when > z)

Have the following query below. I want to select ItemC records but only when it's b.Price > 49.99, while still selecting all ItemA and ItemB records. How do I need to modify my query?

```
SELECT a.ItemType, b.Price
FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Sales b
   ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.SalesDT >= '1 DEC 18'
AND b.MarketID in (1,3)
AND b.MethodID = 3
AND a.ItemType in ('ItemTypeA','ItemTypeB','ItemTypeC')
GROUP BY a.ItemType
ORDER BY b.Price 
   DESC
```

So if all 3 ItemTypes have a Price ranging from 40.00 - 54.99, I would want to pull all sizes for ItemTypeA and ItemTypeB, but only ItemTypeC where Price > 49.99

Comment: You might get a better response if you show some of your data, and include what result you were expecting.

Comment: "I want to select `ItemC` records but only when it's b.Price > 49.99, while still selecting all `ItemA` and `ItemB`" - you mean `ItemTypeA`, `ItemTypeB` and `ItemTypeC` here, aren't you? I suppose you mistyped here and wrote correctly in last sentence - am I wrong or right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I suppose you just need to add 2 predicates with OR:

```
SELECT a.ItemType, b.Price
FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Sales b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.SalesDT >= '1 DEC 18'
AND b.MarketID in (1,3)
AND b.MethodID = 3
AND (
    a.ItemType in ('ItemTypeA','ItemTypeB')
    OR 
    (a.ItemType ='ItemTypeC' AND b.Price > 49.99) 
) 
GROUP BY a.ItemType
ORDER BY b.Price 
DESC
```

Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT a.ItemType, b.Price
FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Sales b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.SalesDT >= '1 DEC 18'
AND b.MarketID in (1,3)
AND b.MethodID = 3
AND 
(
    a.ItemType in ('ItemTypeA','ItemTypeB'
)


GROUP BY a.ItemType
ORDER BY b.Price 
DESC

union all

SELECT a.ItemType, b.Price
FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Sales b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.SalesDT >= '1 DEC 18'
AND b.MarketID in (1,3)
AND b.MethodID = 3
And
    (a.ItemType ='ItemTypeC' AND b.Price > 49.99) 

GROUP BY a.ItemType
ORDER BY b.Price 
DESC
```